# Nice Computational Approach to the generalized "24 Problem"?

Tags: algorithms

I was wondering about the possible existence of an algorithm to essentially play an extended version of the game '24'.

Essentially, we are given N cards, each between 1 and 10. We aim to use the basic operations (+, -, *, /) and parentheses wherever we like to obtain a desired value T using *all* of the cards. Assuming that T is reasonably valued (i.e. not so large that it obviously cannot be reached), does there exist a non-brute force algorithm that finds at least one solution for obtaining T using a set of N cards?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you re-order the numbers?

Comment: Try these techniques: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info